# Why My cart is clear when page reload in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

i am working on woocommerce project. There is problem in this site. i dont want to clear cart when page reload. Currenctly it clears the cart when page reload.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you used empty cart function anywhere in your theme's file: $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

Comment: You need to check woo-commerce settings please read this for more info: http://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-solving-cart-empty-issue/